# How to find first element in a column by group, that fulfills a condition? If the condition is fulfilled start the counter from 0 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset similar to this. I have been trying to add a counter from zero based on a condition of the first element in a column by group.
I want to get liked this:

```
ID YEAR STOf counter
1 2000 0     0
1 2001 1     0
1 2002 0     1
1 2003 0     2
2 2000 0     0
2 2001 0     0
2 2002 1     0
2 2003 0     1
2 2004 0     2
```

I tried this code:

```
ov28<- ov27 %>% group_by(ID, idx = cumsum(STOf == 1L)) %>% 
       mutate(counter = row_number()) %>% 
       ungroup %>% 
       select(-idx)
```

The issue is: counter starts from 1 and the counter needs to start only based on condition as opposed to starting from the new id as well as condition. In short, I want the counter to start only if condition is satisfied, that too from 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a double `cumsum` after grouping by 'ID' and then take the `lag` of the output

```
library(dplyr)
ov27 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(counter2 = lag(cumsum(cumsum(STOf == 1)), default = 0))
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID  YEAR  STOf counter counter2
#  <int> <int> <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#1     1  2000     0       0        0
#2     1  2001     1       0        0
#3     1  2002     0       1        1
#4     1  2003     0       2        2
#5     2  2000     0       0        0
#6     2  2001     0       0        0
#7     2  2002     1       0        0
#8     2  2003     0       1        1
#9     2  2004     0       2        2
```

---

Or create a logical condition and apply `cumsum` once

```
ov27 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(counter2 = cumsum(row_number() > match(1, STOf)))
```

If there are no matches i.e. no 1s in group, specify the `nomatch = n()`

```
ov27 %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(counter2 = cumsum(row_number() > match(1, STOf, nomatch = n())))
```

NOTE: Both methods also work when there are no matches in a group

---

Or using the same logic with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ov27)[, counter2 := cumsum(seq_len(.N) > match(1, STOf)), ID]
```

#### data

```
ov27 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), YEAR = c(2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L), STOf = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), counter = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find the row number when `STOf == 1` and increment the counter from that row.

```
library(dplyr)

ov27 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(counter1 = cumsum(row_number() > which.max(STOf == 1))
  #Can also use which
  #mutate(counter1 = cumsum(row_number() > which(STOf == 1)[1])

#     ID  YEAR  STOf counter counter1
#  <int> <int> <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#1     1  2000     0       0        0
#2     1  2001     1       0        0
#3     1  2002     0       1        1
#4     1  2003     0       2        2
#5     2  2000     0       0        0
#6     2  2001     0       0        0
#7     2  2002     1       0        0
#8     2  2003     0       1        1
#9     2  2004     0       2        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option:

```
DT[, cnt := DT[, pmax(seq(.N) - match(1L, STOf), 0L), ID]$V1]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID YEAR STOf counter
1 2000 0     0
1 2001 1     0
1 2002 0     1
1 2003 0     2
2 2000 0     0
2 2001 0     0
2 2002 1     0
2 2003 0     1
2 2004 0     2")
```